# Why am I getting a JPA @OneToOne Unknown Entity Error?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-one

I am getting the error "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on ca.allauto.ups.model.Vehicle.modelId references an unknown entity: java.lang.Long" for the following classes that have a one-to-one relationship.

The Vehicle (parent class):

```
package ca.allauto.ups.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Vehicle {
    private enum Color {
        Beige,
        Black,
        Blue,
        Brown,
        Burgundy,
        Copper,
        Gold,
        Green,
        Grey,
        Orange,
        Purple,
        Red,
        Silver,
        Teal,
        White,
        Yellow
    }
    
    private enum KmsOrMiles {
        Kms,
        Miles
    }
    
    private enum Transmission {
        Automatic,
        Manual
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="year")
    private short year;
    
    // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC FIELD
    // "id" IS THE PK IN THE "vehicle_model" TABLE
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="model_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Long modelId;
    
    @Column(name="doors")
    private DoorsEnum doors;
    
    @Column(name="vehicle_type")
    private VehicleTypeEnum vehicleType;
    
    @Column(name="color")
    private Color color;
    
    @Column(name="odometer")
    private int odometer;
    
    @Column(name="kms_miles")
    private KmsOrMiles kmsOrMiles;
    
    @Column(name="transmission")
    private Transmission transmission;
    
    @Column(name="vin")
    private String vin;
}
```

The VehicleModel (child) class:

```
package ca.allauto.ups.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle_model")
@Getter
@Setter
public class VehicleModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="model")
    private String model;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "modelId")
    private Vehicle vehicle;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot` in version `>? 3`? If so: You should be using `jakarta` instead of `javax`.

Comment: Are you trying to put the model id (a number) in your Vehicle class, or are you trying to put the model (another entity) in your class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is wrong:

```
private Long modelId;
```

Change to:

```
private VehicleModel modelId;
```

Comment: That did it!  Well, that was easy. :-)